# TypeORM: ManyToMany relation from existing JOIN Table (not modifying db)

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want to define ManyToMany relation in Entity from **existing** JOIN Table.
Is it possible in TypeORM without not modifying any tables on database?
(Creating new Join table is not allowed)

### Example tables

I have three tables like this already, very basic structure of using join table.

1. user Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul |
| 2 | Smith |

2. item table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Helmet |
| 3 | Book |
| 4 | Shoe |

3. user_item table (already existing)

| id | user_id | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

### What I want to get

results something like this

```
type User = {
  id:number
  name:string
  items: Item[]
}
type Item = {
  id:number
  name:string
  users: User[]
}
```

---

How can I define User Entity and Item Entity?

I have read other documents, but everyone doing this with creating new join table on TypeORM, such as @JoinTable. But I can't modify any tables